# Switch SLF4J SimpleLogger properties file with Maven

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I've got a typical Maven project structure with the `simplelogger.properties` file on the classpath:

```
+MyProject
`-- src
    |-- main/java/com.mypackage.MyClass
    `-- resources
        `-- simplelogger.properties
```

This works perfectly from the IDE as the correct SimpleLogger configuration is already on the classpath.
I'd like to have another `simplelogger.properties` file in the packaged finished .jar (output to file instead of to System.out).

Is there a way to replace the `simplelogger.properties` on the classpath file with another `simplelogger.properties` file from somewhere else with Maven when packaging a .jar?

Comment: Tricky but surely it's not too much trouble to do it manually? If you wanted to avoid doing it manually, you could use `git` and check out a different version before running `mvn package`

Comment: This is based on my understanding on the fact that you want that config *in the jar and active*.

Comment: I could do it manually, and that's what I'll do if I don't find something better

Comment: `git` would solve it for you and would be a good tool for your source control of course anyway

Comment: @g00se how exactly do you solve it with git?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the `mvn package` operation would operate on the file(s) you have checked out at the time, so you'd simply check out the log config that logs to file instead of console

Comment: @g00se I don’t think your approach will work well.  This is generally not how you do it in a build server.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It would actually just be how it worked by default if you happened to be using git. I take it you don't ;)

Comment: @g00se i use git.  Do you use a build server?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat an X-Y problem.  I would suggest doing this instead:

Have two modules.  The one you have, and put your simplelogger configuration file in the *test* part of the classpath.  This will ensure it doesn't go in the resulting jar (which is much of the reason for your current problem).

Then have a deployment module which adds the deployment configuration file to your artifact from above in the form you need it.  When you get to needing multiple deployments just create a module for each.

Answer (score 0):

If your jar file has already been built you could override your properties:

```
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=D:\wherever\new-logger.properties
```

However, I checked it for Spring Boot projects.

You could check more information here:

- [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

Comment: I'm not using Spring Boot sadly

Answer (score 0):

When you're running your application, you can place the  `simplelogger.properties` file in your class path or working directory of your program.

```
`-- work-dir
    |-- myApp.jar
    `-- simplelogger.properties
```

If your application runs properly in IDE and if it isn't running properly when packaged, maybe your JAR file doesn't contain the resources. In that case, you can use the following configuration in your `pom.xml` file to copy the resources to your JAR file.

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/customize</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I just tested it, the properties file must be in the classpath (aka in the jar itself), it won't work if it's next to the jar. The application works properly both in the IDE and when packaged, but the properties file must be inside the jar